# Help with the use 'to' or 'of'

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Could you use to in this sense?- "Property 'to' men" or does it have to be "Property 'of' men"

Comment: Depends on the context. Consider this: "The tyrant gave all his property to the men in the family; the women were left penniless." You can use "to" when you are talking about transferring property. You use "of" when you are saying the property belongs to someone.

Answer (score 1):

*Property* (a noun) takes "of" for its owner. There doesn't happen to be a verb derived from *property* that expresses that relationship.

*Belong* (a verb) expresses that relationship, and takes "to" for its owner.

*Own* (a verb) has the owner as its subject, and the property as its direct object.

There is no rule, or particular reason, why this should be so: it is just the way those particular words happen to behave in current English.

Answer (score 0):

> **The property belongs to David.**
>
> **The property of David  has been donated to an orphanage**
>
> **The property of John has been increasing by leaps and bounds**

The  first sentence means David owns the property.

The second sentence means David's property has been donated.

Third sentence  means John's property is increasing.

You can use **to** or **of** based on the context.

Comment: In no case does the _to_ go with "property". In the first sentence it attaches to _belong_, and in the second case _to _donate(d)_.